# how to stick gallery in left side insted of center in all device?

Tags: android

When the Gallery first displays, it is centering the first item automatically. The behavior I want, is to left align the first item in the parent layout instead of centering it. How can I achieve this in all device?

Comment: discover this link
same Q:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341158/android-align-first-item-in-gallery-to-the-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tough to implement this in Gallery view. So, You have to use the other better way to use HorizontalListview for that.

Refer this [HorizontalVariableListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView)

Good luck.....

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity property to left:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#setGravity(int)

some constant values:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#attr_android:gravity